# Dynamic Control names in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    "student" + i.ToString().Text = students[i];
}
```

I already have many labels which each one has name like:
student1
student2
student3
.
.

But I got this error:
Error   1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   F:\Homework\Homework\Form1.cs   161 46  Homework

Any help please??!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have dynamic variable names, in just about *any* language.

Looks like you are looking to have a *collection* or *array* of controls.

Something like:

```
var studentControls = new List<Control>();
studentControls.Add(student1); 
studentControls.Add(student2);
...
for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    studentControls[i].Text = students[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Controls.Find("student" + i.ToString())

Comment: May or may not work, depending on what platform this is on (winforms? webforms? WPF? Windows phone?)

Comment: F:\Homework\Homework\Form1.cs 161 46 Homework - Form1.cs - I guess it WinForms

Answer (score 3):

this may help

```
Controls.Find(string.Format("student{0}", i));
```

**A better solution:**

Set the `Tag` property of you `Labels` as follow:

```
Student1.Tag = 1;
Student2.Tag = 2;
Student3.Tag = 3;
```

I assume that your `Labels` are in a container control named `container`. use this code:

```
foreach(var item in container.Children) //based on your container type this line may change
{
    if(item is Label)
    {
        Label temp = ((Label)item);
        temp.Text = students[int.Parse(temp.Tag.ToString())]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can omit .ToString() method because string.Format uses it already by default.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `i.ToString()` you are given a string, which does not have the property Text :). That is what is causing your exception.

If `Students` is a list of controls that have the property `.Text` then use that and remove the `ToString()` else, remove the `.Text`.